# Is RouteExistingFiles no longer part of asp.net 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I search github source and http://docs.asp.net/en/latest, but can't find any documentation for RouteExistingFiles. I've tried adding it onto `routes.RouteExistingFiles`, but this won't compile. **Has this option be removed or rethought? Can it be accessed from the StartUp?**

```
public class Startup
{

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddMvc()
            .AddRouting();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        StaticFileOptions option = new StaticFileOptions();
        FileExtensionContentTypeProvider contentTypeProvider = (FileExtensionContentTypeProvider) option.ContentTypeProvider;
        contentTypeProvider.Mappings.Add(".yqs", "text/plain");   

        app
            .UseStaticFiles(option)
            .UseDefaultFiles()
            .UseFileServer()
            .UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    "YQ Controller",
                    "{*src}",
                    new { controller = "YQFile", action = "OnDemand" },
                    new { src = @"(.*?)\.(yqs)" }
                );
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: [MSDN documentation for RouteExistingFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.routeexistingfiles(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yes, right. However this is for the older versions of asp.net. I'm trying to determine if asp.net 5 still has or has changed this feature.

Comment: You need to show us in your code where you are attempting to call or set `routes.RouteExistingFiles`.  I assumed this has worked before?

Comment: I've tried it in `app.UseMvc(routes => { routes.RouteExistingFiles = true; });`

Comment: What is the compiler error message?

Comment: 'IRouteBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'RouteExistingFiles' and no extension method 'RouteExistingFiles' accepting a first argument of type 'IRouteBuilder' could be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) --> demo.DNX Core 5.0 && demo.DNX 4.5.1

Comment: `IRouteBuilder` doesn't appear to be part of ASP.NET proper.

Comment: Yes? I know. Have you read my question?

Comment: This isn't a question of something getting obsoleted.  It's a simple troubleshooting problem.  The object you've hooked up doesn't have `IRouteBuilder`.  Find one that does.

Comment: I don't think that will have any benefit either. https://github.com/aspnet/Routing/blob/352732fc62c6ab2984122093416133131d26ff15/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Routing/RouteCollection.cs

Comment: Did RouteCollection ever have that member?

Comment: Yes, as per the link in your first comment.

Comment: Did it ever work the way you called it in the comment above?

Comment: This used to work from the global.asax.cs and RouteConfig.cs.

Comment: Is that where you're calling it from now?

Comment: No. This called from the StartUp.cs. I figured this was inferred.

Comment: Are you still calling it from global.asax.cs or routeconfig.cs?  See, this is what happens when questions are incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I can't find any documentation, it seems this option isn't in asp.net 5. Now, it seems that routing and other configuration in `StartUp.Configure()` will take precedence over proceeding configuration. So, bringing the `app.UseMvc()` configuration forward in the chain will allow the route to take priority over `app.UseStaticFiles()`.

```
public class Startup
{

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddMvc()
            .AddRouting();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app
            .UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    "YQ Controller",
                    "{*src}",
                    new { controller = "YQFile", action = "OnDemand" },
                    new { src = @"(.*?)\.(yqs)" }
                );
            })
            .UseStaticFiles()
            .UseDefaultFiles()
            .UseFileServer();
    }
}
```